# How to set `Copy user password reset e-mail to manager ` in OIM 11gr2ps3?

Tags: configuration, system, oim

I need to set `Copy user password reset e-mail to manager` which Specifies whether the manager of the user whose password is being reset must be notified of this password reset.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27559_01/admin.1112/e27149/system_props.htm#OMADM884

As per the above link there is a property which sends email to user's manager on password reset in 11gR2 but I dont see the same in PS3 also suppose I create the same in system configuration what should be the value for the same?

Comment: similar system property exists in OIM PS3 but it sends email to manager if email for the subordinate is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the information provided in the below URL for system properties `XL.NotifyUserCreateToOther` & `XL.NotifyPasswordGenerationToOther`:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52734_01/oim/OMADM/system_props.htm#OMADM884

It says: When the value of this property is TRUE, the email notification for reset password is sent to other recipients if the email ID of the user is not specified. So if the user already has an email then his/her manager won't get any email. The full scenario would be like this:

1. `XL.NotifiyPasswordGenerationToOther` = `TRUE` (PASSWORD RESET TEST)

   - User has email, Mgr has email -> User gets notification
   - User has no email, Mgr has email -> Mgr gets notification
   - User has email, Mgr has no email -> User gets notification
   - User has no email, Mgr has no email -> Error
2. `XL.NotifiyPasswordGenerationToOther` = `FALSE` (PASSWORD RESET TEST)

   - User has email, Mgr has email -> User gets notification
   - User has no email, Mgr has email -> Error
   - User has email, Mgr has no email -> User gets notification
   - User has no email, Mgr has no email -> Error